# Camlquery exists in both microsoft.sharepoint.client, version 15.0 and Microsoft.sharepoint.client , version 16.1

Tags: sharepoint-online

When i tried to add Microsoft.sharepointonline.CSOM.dll, version 16.1 to my project which already had microsoft.sharepoint.client,version 15.0 as reference, i received a bunch of errors saying the type exists in both version 15.0 and 16.1

example: Camlquery exists in both microsoft.sharepoint.client, version 15.0 and Microsoft.sharepoint.client , version 16.1

Is it a DLL conflict? why does visual studio say Microsoft.sharepoint.client Version 16.1 when i didn't add that?

Does microsoft.sharepoint.client version 15.0 and microsoft.sharepointonline.CSOM version 16.1 conflict each other?

I tried the below but nothing helped.
 1. closing and opening Visual studio
 2. clean solution
 3. IIS Reset
 4. deleting obj and bin folder contents
 5. Deleting microsoft.sharepoint.client 15.0 from reference. But the code while run time, it is looking for microsoft.sharepoint.client v15.0

Comment: Okay, it looks like Microsoft.Sharepoint.client is part of Microsoft.sharepointonline.CSOM.

Answer (score 0):

removing Microsoft.sharpeoint.client 15.0 and adding microsoft.sharepointonline.csom worked.